# Why is this ambiguous? What can I do to fix this?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++14, bit-fields

This is in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, in C++. It says the statement `bigbits<2> ok2 = (ok >> sq) & 1;` is ambiguous. How is it ambiguous, and what can I do to fix it?

Here is the code.

**bigbits.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bigbits.h"

int main()
{
    bigbits<2> ok = 0x10101010;
    int sq = 5;
    bigbits<2> ok2 = (ok >> sq) & 1;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

**bigbits.h**

```
#ifndef BIGBITS_H_
#define BIGBITS_H_

#include <cinttypes>
#include <utility>

constexpr uint32_t lower_dword(uint64_t n) {
    return (uint32_t)(n & UINT32_MAX);
}

constexpr uint32_t upper_dword(uint64_t n) {
    return (uint32_t)(n >> 32);
}

template<uint32_t n> class bigbits;

template<> 
class bigbits<0U> {};

template<> 
class bigbits<1U> {
private:
    uint32_t m_head;

    constexpr void rshft(uint32_t n) {
        m_head >>= n;
    }

    constexpr void lshft(uint32_t n) {
        m_head <<= n;
    }

    constexpr void b_or(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head |= other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr void b_and(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head &= other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr void b_xor(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head ^= other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr void b_not() {
        m_head = ~m_head;
    }

    constexpr uint32_t rshft_(uint32_t n) {
        uint32_t carry = m_head & ((1 << n) - 1);
        m_head >>= n;
        return carry;
    }

    constexpr void lshft_(uint32_t n, uint32_t carry) {
        m_head <<= n;
        m_head |= carry >> (32 - n);
    }

    constexpr void minus_one_() {
        m_head = m_head == 0 ? UINT32_MAX : m_head - 1;
    }

public:
    constexpr bigbits() : m_head(0) {}
    constexpr bigbits(const bigbits& other) : m_head(other.m_head) {}
    constexpr bigbits(uint32_t n) : m_head(n) {}
    constexpr bigbits(int n) : bigbits((uint32_t)n) {}
    constexpr bigbits(uint64_t n) : m_head(lower_dword(n)) {}

    constexpr bigbits& operator=(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head = other.m_head;
        return *this;
    }
    constexpr bigbits& operator=(uint32_t n) {
        m_head = n;
        return *this;
    }
    constexpr bigbits& operator=(int n) {
        return operator=((uint32_t)n);
    }
    constexpr bigbits& operator=(uint64_t n) {
        m_head = lower_dword(n);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr operator uint32_t() const {
        return m_head;
    }

    constexpr operator int() const {
        return (int)m_head;
    }

    constexpr operator uint64_t() const {
        return (uint64_t)m_head;
    }

    constexpr operator bool() const {
        return (bool)m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(const bigbits& other) const {
        return m_head == other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(uint32_t n) const {
        return m_head == n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(int n) const {
        return operator==((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(const bigbits& other) const {
        return m_head != other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(uint32_t n) const {
        return m_head != n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(int n) const {
        return operator!=((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(const bigbits& other) const {
        return m_head < other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(uint32_t n) const {
        return m_head < n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(int n) const {
        return operator<((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator>(const bigbits& other) const {
        return m_head > other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>(uint32_t n) const {
        return m_head > n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>(int n) const {
        return operator>((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator<=(const bigbits& other) const {
        return m_head <= other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<=(uint32_t n) const {
        return m_head <= n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<=(int n) const {
        return operator<=((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator>=(const bigbits& other) const {
        return m_head >= other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>=(uint32_t n) const {
        return m_head >= n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>=(int n) const {
        return operator>=((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator>>=(uint32_t n) {
        rshft(n);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator>>=(int n) {
        return *this >>= (uint32_t)n;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator<<=(uint32_t n) {
        lshft(n);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator<<=(int n) {
        return *this <<= (uint32_t)n;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator|=(const bigbits& other) {
        b_or(other);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator&=(const bigbits& other) {
        b_and(other);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator^=(const bigbits& other) {
        b_xor(other);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits operator~() const {
        bigbits ret = *this;
        ret.b_not();
        return ret;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& minus_one() {
        minus_one_();
        return *this;
    }

    friend class bigbits<2>;

};

template<uint32_t n>
class bigbits : protected bigbits<n-1U> {
private:
    uint32_t m_head;

    typedef bigbits<n - 1U> inherited;

    constexpr inherited& tail() { return *this; }
    constexpr const inherited& tail() const { return *this; }

    constexpr void rshft(uint32_t n) {
        while (n > 0) {
            uint32_t t = n > 31 ? 31 : n;
            rshft_(t);
            n -= t;
        }
    }

    constexpr void lshft(uint32_t n) {
        while (n > 0) {
            uint32_t t = n > 31 ? 31 : n;
            lshft_(t, 0);
            n -= t;
        }
    }

    constexpr void b_or(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head |= other.m_head;
        tail().b_or(other.tail());
    }

    constexpr void b_and(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head &= other.m_head;
        tail().b_xor(other.tail());
    }

    constexpr void b_xor(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head ^= other.m_head;
        tail().b_xor(other.tail());
    }

    constexpr void b_not() {
        m_head = ~m_head;
        tail().b_not();
    }

    constexpr uint32_t rshft_(uint32_t n) {
        uint32_t carry = m_head & ((1 << n) - 1);
        m_head >>= n;
        m_head |= tail().rshft_(n) << (32 - n);
        return carry;
    }

    constexpr void lshft_(uint32_t n, uint32_t carry) {
        uint32_t carry2 = m_head & (UINT32_MAX ^ ((1 << (32 - n)) - 1));
        m_head <<= n;
        m_head |= carry >> (32 - n);
        tail().lshft_(n, carry2);
    }

    //returns a reference
    constexpr void minus_one_() {
        if (m_head == 0) {
            m_head = UINT32_MAX;
            tail().minus_one_();
        }
        else {
            m_head -= 1;
        }
    }

public:
    constexpr bigbits() : m_head(0), inherited(0) {}
    constexpr bigbits(const bigbits& other) : m_head(other.m_head), inherited(other.tail()) {}
    constexpr bigbits(uint32_t n) : m_head(n), inherited(0U) {}
    constexpr bigbits(int n) : bigbits((uint32_t)n) {}
    constexpr bigbits(uint64_t n) : m_head(lower_dword(n)), inherited(upper_dword(n)) {}

    constexpr bigbits& operator=(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head = other.m_head;
        tail() = other.tail();
        return *this;
    }
    constexpr bigbits& operator=(uint32_t n) {
        m_head = n;
        tail() = 0U;
        return *this;
    }
    constexpr bigbits& operator=(int n) {
        return operator=((uint32_t)n);
    }
    constexpr bigbits& operator=(uint64_t n) {
        m_head = lower_dword(n);
        tail() = upper_dword(n);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr operator uint32_t() const {
        return m_head;
    }

    constexpr operator int() const {
        return (int)m_head;
    }

    constexpr operator uint64_t() const {
        return (uint64_t)m_head | ((uint64_t)(uint32_t)tail() << 32);
    }

    constexpr operator bool() const {
        return (bool)m_head || (bool)tail();
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(const bigbits& other) const {
        return (m_head == other.m_head) && (tail() == other.tail());
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(uint32_t n) const {
        return (m_head == n) && (tail() == 0);
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(int n) const {
        return operator==((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(const bigbits& other) const {
        return (m_head != other.m_head) && (tail() != other.tail());
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(uint32_t n) const {
        return (m_head != n) && (tail() != 0);
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(int n) const {
        return operator!=((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(const bigbits& other) const {
        if (tail() < other.tail())
            return true;
        else if (tail() > other.tail())
            return false;
        else
            return m_head < other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(uint32_t n) const {
        if (tail() > 0) return false;
        else return m_head < n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(int n) const {
        return operator<((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator>(const bigbits& other) const {
        if (tail() > other.tail())
            return true;
        else if (tail() < other.tail())
            return false;
        else
            return m_head > other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>(uint32_t n) const {
        if (tail() > 0) return true;
        else return m_head < n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>(int n) const {
        return operator>((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator<=(const bigbits& other) const {
        if (tail() < other.tail())
            return true;
        else if (tail() > other.tail())
            return false;
        else
            return m_head <= other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<=(uint32_t n) const {
        if (tail() != 0) return false;
        else return m_head <= n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<=(int n) const {
        return operator<=((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator>=(const bigbits& other) const {
        if (tail() > other.tail())
            return true;
        else if (tail() < other.tail())
            return false;
        else
            return m_head >= other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>=(uint32_t n) const {
        if (tail() != 0) return true;
        else return m_head >= n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>=(int n) const {
        return operator>=((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator>>=(uint32_t n) {
        rshft(n);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator>>=(int n) {
        return *this >>= (uint32_t)n;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator<<=(uint32_t n) {
        lshft(n);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator<<=(int n) {
        return *this <<= (uint32_t)n;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator|=(const bigbits& other) {
        b_or(other);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator&=(const bigbits& other) {
        b_and(other);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator^=(const bigbits& other) {
        b_xor(other);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits operator~() const {
        bigbits ret = *this;
        ret.b_not();
        return ret;
    }

    //returns a reference
    constexpr bigbits& minus_one() {
        minus_one_();
        return *this;
    }

    friend class bigbits<n + 1U>;

};

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator>>(const bigbits<a>& first, uint32_t n) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret >>= n;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator>>(const bigbits<a>& first, int n) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret >>= n;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator<<(const bigbits<a>& first, uint32_t n) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret <<= n;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator<<(const bigbits<a>& first, int n) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret <<= n;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator|(const bigbits<a>& first, const bigbits<a>& second) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret |= second;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator&(const bigbits<a>& first, const bigbits<a>& second) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret &= second;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator^(const bigbits<a>& first, const bigbits<a>& second) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret ^= second;
}

//returns a copy
template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> minus_one(const bigbits<a>& first) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret.minus_one();
}

template<uint32_t a, class Head>
constexpr void assign_bigbits2_(bigbits<a>& b, Head&& h) {
    b |= h;
}

template<uint32_t a, class Head, class...Tail>
constexpr void assign_bigbits2_(bigbits<a>& b, Head&& h, Tail&&...t) {
    b |= h;
    b <<= 32;
    assign_bigbits2_(b, std::forward<Tail>(t)...);
}

template<class...Args>
constexpr bigbits<sizeof...(Args)> assign_bigbits(Args&&...args) {
    bigbits<sizeof...(Args)> ret = 0;
    assign_bigbits2_(ret, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return ret;
}

#endif
```

Comment: The code in the question should be self-contained, not linking to external files

Comment: ^^ e.g., your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And post full error message, it should list the different possible overloads.

Comment: Just scanning through your code, I guess your `operator&` is ambiguous. I cannot tell for sure as the bigbits class has multiple flaws.

Comment: T.J. Crowder: "Please put a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example in the question." If I put bigbits.h in the body of the question, it will say too much of the question is code. So I cannot do what you are asking me to do.

Comment: mkaes: "Just scanning through your code, I guess your operator& is ambiguous. I cannot tell for sure as the bigbits class has multiple flaws." Such as? Please be specific.

Comment: mkaes: The overloads are: operator&(uint32_t, int), operator&(int, int), operator&(uint64_t, int), and operator&(bool, int). JeJo edited the code in, but I'm not able to edit the overloads in.

Comment: @beneficii: "*If I put bigbits.h in the body of the question, it will say too much of the question is code. So I cannot do what you are asking me to do.*" Then reduce `bitbits` to just the parts that are causing the problem. This is the "minimal" part of an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I have fixed it. I have added more overloads of **bigbits::operator&()**. The problem is that it was trying to cast **bigbits** to one of the basic types (like int or bool). Further testing shows the main problem was with the logic of **bigbits::operator!=()**. I have now fixed it.

The purpose of this project was to be able to expand the bitboards of the open-source chess engine Senpai 1.0 (released under the GNU General Public License) to larger chessboards. I have now succeeded in having Senpai use **bigbits** instead of **uint64** for its bitboards. Testing it in WinBoard, there does not seem to be any significant performance hit, in terms of the strength of the engine, the validity of the moves, or in how fast it runs. This is because I used C++11 templates and C++14-version **constexpr**, which moves the bulk of the calculations to compile time, allowing for a minimum of calculations in runtime. As 64-bit integers already take longer time than 32-bit integers (because the latter is native to most modern-day systems), there was no significant performance hit with the extra calculations of **bigbits**.

Here is the updated bigbits.h code. For the functions not used by Senpai, I cannot guarantee 100% that the functions are correct, but it is usable in Senpai:

```
/*
Bigbits Copyright (C) 2018 beneficii.

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/

#ifndef BIGBITS_H_
#define BIGBITS_H_

#include <cinttypes>
#include <utility>

constexpr uint32_t lower_dword(uint64_t n) {
    return (uint32_t)(n & UINT32_MAX);
}

constexpr uint32_t upper_dword(uint64_t n) {
    return (uint32_t)(n >> 32);
}

template<uint32_t n> class bigbits;

template<> 
class bigbits<0U> {};

template<> 
class bigbits<1U> {
private:
    uint32_t m_head;

    constexpr void rshft(uint32_t n) {
        m_head >>= n;
    }

    constexpr void lshft(uint32_t n) {
        m_head <<= n;
    }

    constexpr void b_or(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head |= other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr void b_and(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head &= other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr void b_xor(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head ^= other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr void b_not() {
        m_head = ~m_head;
    }

    constexpr uint32_t rshft_(uint32_t n) {
        uint32_t carry = m_head & ((1 << n) - 1);
        m_head >>= n;
        return carry;
    }

    constexpr void lshft_(uint32_t n, uint32_t carry) {
        m_head <<= n;
        m_head |= carry >> (32 - n);
    }

    constexpr void minus_one_() {
        m_head = m_head == 0 ? UINT32_MAX : m_head - 1;
    }

public:
    constexpr bigbits() : m_head(0) {}
    constexpr bigbits(const bigbits& other) : m_head(other.m_head) {}
    constexpr bigbits(uint32_t n) : m_head(n) {}
    constexpr bigbits(int n) : bigbits((uint32_t)n) {}
    constexpr bigbits(uint64_t n) : m_head(lower_dword(n)) {}

    constexpr bigbits& operator=(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head = other.m_head;
        return *this;
    }
    constexpr bigbits& operator=(uint32_t n) {
        m_head = n;
        return *this;
    }
    constexpr bigbits& operator=(int n) {
        return operator=((uint32_t)n);
    }
    constexpr bigbits& operator=(uint64_t n) {
        m_head = lower_dword(n);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr operator uint32_t() const {
        return m_head;
    }

    constexpr operator int() const {
        return (int)m_head;
    }

    constexpr operator uint64_t() const {
        return (uint64_t)m_head;
    }

    constexpr operator bool() const {
        return (bool)m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(const bigbits& other) const {
        return m_head == other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(uint32_t n) const {
        return m_head == n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(int n) const {
        return operator==((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(const bigbits& other) const {
        return m_head != other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(uint32_t n) const {
        return m_head != n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(int n) const {
        return operator!=((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(const bigbits& other) const {
        return m_head < other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(uint32_t n) const {
        return m_head < n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(int n) const {
        return operator<((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator>(const bigbits& other) const {
        return m_head > other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>(uint32_t n) const {
        return m_head > n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>(int n) const {
        return operator>((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator<=(const bigbits& other) const {
        return m_head <= other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<=(uint32_t n) const {
        return m_head <= n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<=(int n) const {
        return operator<=((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator>=(const bigbits& other) const {
        return m_head >= other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>=(uint32_t n) const {
        return m_head >= n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>=(int n) const {
        return operator>=((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator>>=(uint32_t n) {
        rshft(n);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator>>=(int n) {
        return *this >>= (uint32_t)n;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator<<=(uint32_t n) {
        lshft(n);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator<<=(int n) {
        return *this <<= (uint32_t)n;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator|=(const bigbits& other) {
        b_or(other);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator&=(const bigbits& other) {
        b_and(other);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator^=(const bigbits& other) {
        b_xor(other);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits operator~() const {
        bigbits ret = *this;
        ret.b_not();
        return ret;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& minus_one() {
        minus_one_();
        return *this;
    }

    friend class bigbits<2>;

};

template<uint32_t n>
class bigbits : protected bigbits<n-1U> {
private:
    uint32_t m_head;

    typedef bigbits<n - 1U> inherited;

    constexpr inherited& tail() { return *this; }
    constexpr const inherited& tail() const { return *this; }

    constexpr void rshft(uint32_t n) {
        while (n > 0) {
            uint32_t t = n > 31 ? 31 : n;
            rshft_(t);
            n -= t;
        }
    }

    constexpr void lshft(uint32_t n) {
        while (n > 0) {
            uint32_t t = n > 31 ? 31 : n;
            lshft_(t, 0);
            n -= t;
        }
    }

    constexpr void b_or(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head |= other.m_head;
        tail().b_or(other.tail());
    }

    constexpr void b_and(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head &= other.m_head;
        tail().b_and(other.tail());
    }

    constexpr void b_xor(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head ^= other.m_head;
        tail().b_xor(other.tail());
    }

    constexpr void b_not() {
        m_head = ~m_head;
        tail().b_not();
    }

    constexpr uint32_t rshft_(uint32_t n) {
        uint32_t carry = m_head & ((1 << n) - 1);
        m_head >>= n;
        m_head |= tail().rshft_(n) << (32 - n);
        return carry;
    }

    constexpr void lshft_(uint32_t n, uint32_t carry) {
        uint32_t carry2 = m_head & (UINT32_MAX ^ ((1 << (32 - n)) - 1));
        m_head <<= n;
        m_head |= carry >> (32 - n);
        tail().lshft_(n, carry2);
    }

    //returns a reference
    constexpr void minus_one_() {
        if (m_head == 0) {
            m_head = UINT32_MAX;
            tail().minus_one_();
        }
        else {
            m_head -= 1;
        }
    }

public:
    constexpr bigbits() : m_head(0), inherited(0) {}
    constexpr bigbits(const bigbits& other) : m_head(other.m_head), inherited(other.tail()) {}
    constexpr bigbits(uint32_t n) : m_head(n), inherited(0U) {}
    constexpr bigbits(int n) : bigbits((uint32_t)n) {}
    constexpr bigbits(uint64_t n) : m_head(lower_dword(n)), inherited(upper_dword(n)) {}

    constexpr bigbits& operator=(const bigbits& other) {
        m_head = other.m_head;
        tail() = other.tail();
        return *this;
    }
    constexpr bigbits& operator=(uint32_t n) {
        m_head = n;
        tail() = 0U;
        return *this;
    }
    constexpr bigbits& operator=(int n) {
        return operator=((uint32_t)n);
    }
    constexpr bigbits& operator=(uint64_t n) {
        m_head = lower_dword(n);
        tail() = upper_dword(n);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr operator uint32_t() const {
        return m_head;
    }

    constexpr operator int() const {
        return (int)m_head;
    }

    constexpr operator uint64_t() const {
        return (uint64_t)m_head | ((uint64_t)(uint32_t)tail() << 32);
    }

    constexpr operator bool() const {
        return (bool)m_head || (bool)tail();
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(const bigbits& other) const {
        return (m_head == other.m_head) && (tail() == other.tail());
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(uint32_t n) const {
        return (m_head == n) && (tail() == 0);
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(int n) const {
        return operator==((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(const bigbits& other) const {
        return !operator==(other);
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(uint32_t n) const {
        return !operator==(n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(int n) const {
        return operator!=((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(const bigbits& other) const {
        if (tail() < other.tail())
            return true;
        else if (tail() > other.tail())
            return false;
        else
            return m_head < other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(uint32_t n) const {
        if (tail() > 0) return false;
        else return m_head < n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(int n) const {
        return operator<((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator>(const bigbits& other) const {
        if (tail() > other.tail())
            return true;
        else if (tail() < other.tail())
            return false;
        else
            return m_head > other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>(uint32_t n) const {
        if (tail() > 0) return true;
        else return m_head < n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>(int n) const {
        return operator>((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator<=(const bigbits& other) const {
        if (tail() < other.tail())
            return true;
        else if (tail() > other.tail())
            return false;
        else
            return m_head <= other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<=(uint32_t n) const {
        if (tail() != 0) return false;
        else return m_head <= n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<=(int n) const {
        return operator<=((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bool operator>=(const bigbits& other) const {
        if (tail() > other.tail())
            return true;
        else if (tail() < other.tail())
            return false;
        else
            return m_head >= other.m_head;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>=(uint32_t n) const {
        if (tail() != 0) return true;
        else return m_head >= n;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>=(int n) const {
        return operator>=((uint32_t)n);
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator>>=(uint32_t n) {
        rshft(n);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator>>=(int n) {
        return *this >>= (uint32_t)n;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator<<=(uint32_t n) {
        lshft(n);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator<<=(int n) {
        return *this <<= (uint32_t)n;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator|=(const bigbits& other) {
        b_or(other);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator&=(const bigbits& other) {
        b_and(other);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits& operator^=(const bigbits& other) {
        b_xor(other);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bigbits operator~() const {
        bigbits ret = *this;
        ret.b_not();
        return ret;
    }

    //returns a reference
    constexpr bigbits& minus_one() {
        minus_one_();
        return *this;
    }

    friend class bigbits<n + 1U>;

};

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator>>(const bigbits<a>& first, uint32_t n) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret >>= n;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator>>(const bigbits<a>& first, int n) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret >>= n;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator<<(const bigbits<a>& first, uint32_t n) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret <<= n;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator<<(const bigbits<a>& first, int n) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret <<= n;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator|(const bigbits<a>& first, const bigbits<a>& second) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret |= second;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator|(const bigbits<a>& first, uint32_t n) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret |= n;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator|(const bigbits<a>& first, int n) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret |= n;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator&(const bigbits<a>& first, const bigbits<a>& second) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret &= second;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator&(const bigbits<a>& first, uint32_t n) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret &= n;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator&(const bigbits<a>& first, int n) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret &= n;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator^(const bigbits<a>& first, const bigbits<a>& second) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret ^= second;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator^(const bigbits<a>& first, uint32_t n) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret ^= n;
}

template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> operator^(const bigbits<a>& first, int n) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret ^= n;
}

//returns a copy
template<uint32_t a>
constexpr bigbits<a> minus_one(const bigbits<a>& first) {
    bigbits<a> ret = first;
    return ret.minus_one();
}

template<uint32_t a, class Head>
constexpr void assign_bigbits2_(bigbits<a>& b, Head&& h) {
    b |= h;
}

template<uint32_t a, class Head, class...Tail>
constexpr void assign_bigbits2_(bigbits<a>& b, Head&& h, Tail&&...t) {
    b |= h;
    b <<= 32;
    assign_bigbits2_(b, std::forward<Tail>(t)...);
}

template<class...Args>
constexpr bigbits<sizeof...(Args)> assign_bigbits(Args&&...args) {
    bigbits<sizeof...(Args)> ret = 0;
    assign_bigbits2_(ret, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return ret;
}

#endif
```

To utilize in Senpai 1.0, include **bigbits.h**, replace **typedef uint64 bit_t;** with **typedef bigbits<2> bit_t;**, and in the function **bit::rest()** replace **(b - 1)** with **minus_one(b)**.